# screencapture output format

Tags: android

I am trying to use the `/system/bin/screencapture` tool in Android in my program. I want to have the screenshot in a Bitmap object. (I know about the other methods, however, my program is using a `SurfaceView` and I cannot change that so none available on the internet I could find worked.)

I have found that using the `-p` option to encode it into a png file takes too much time. So I want to use the output without the `-p` option. However, I am unable to figure out what format that output uses. I have tried reading it into a byte array and using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` but that doesn't seem to work (method just returns `null`.)

TL;DR: What format does `/system/bin/screencapture` use when not using the `-p` option (or writing to a file name that ends with ".png")

Here's the relevant code:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap /storage/emulated/0/storage/screencap");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(45);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("findMe", "Finished writing file");
        byte[] data = new byte[0];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/system/bin/screencap");
        while(fis.available() > 0){
            data = append_to_byte_arr(data, (byte) fis.read());
        }
        Log.d("findMe", data.length + " is data.length");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("findMe", "you failed", ioe);
        return;
    }

    //...

    private byte[] append_to_byte_arr(byte[] arr, byte item) {
        byte[] temp = new byte[arr.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, temp, 0, arr.length);
        temp[arr.length] = item;
        return temp;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the "-p" option the format depends about the filename extension: if it is ".png" the screenshot is automatically saved as PNG. Without any filename the screenshot is printed to "stdout". I tried many was and the best is to print out to "stdout" and then read directly the Bitmap pixels from there because the other methods involves the "screencap" to save to file and then your App should read it wasting "a lot of time" (near 1.5 seconds in both operations)

Comment: Will do. Out of curiosity, though, which format is used when printing to stdout without the `-p` option?

Comment: Pure RGB pixels without the Bitmap header at the beginning